# SQL Hash condition returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hash

Very simple scenario:

```
SELECT 'abc' as [field1]
        ,HASHBYTES('MD5','abc') AS [Hash]
INTO #test
```

Creates table. 
I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM #test
```

It returns 1 record as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM #test 
WHERE [field1] = 'abc'
```

This returns 1 record. I copy the value from [Hash] field and query again:

```
SELECT * FROM #test 
WHERE [Hash] = '0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72'
```

This returns no records. Why? Is hash field saved/treated in any special way? I expected it will be text as any other, which I can query. Is there any workaround?

P.S. `Hash LIKE '%%'` does not help.

Comment: `hashbytes` returns a `varbinary`, which ends up in the table. You are comparing it to a `varchar`.

Comment: `[Hash] = 0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72`

Comment: varbinary literals are not enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) returns `varbinary (maximum 8000 bytes)`. And you are using quotes `'0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72'` that makes it `varchar`. Convertion from `varchar` to `varbinary` is explicit (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx), *Implicit Conversions* part). So you need to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #test 
WHERE [Hash] = 0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #test 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),[Hash],1) = '0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72'
```

This is explonation what is `Style = 1` in previous query:

```
DECLARE @varbin varbinary(max)

SELECT @varbin = CONVERT(varbinary(max),'Something')

SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(max), @varbin, 0) AS [Style 0, binary to character],
        CONVERT(varchar(max), @varbin, 1) AS [Style 1, binary to character],
        CONVERT(varchar(max), @varbin, 2) AS [Style 2, binary to character]
```

Will return:

```
Style 0, binary to character    Style 1, binary to character    Style 2, binary to character
Something                       0x536F6D657468696E67            536F6D657468696E67
```

Hope, that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Take off Parentehsis

```
select * from #test where [Hash] = 0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72
select * from #test where  cast([Hash] as varchar(max)) = 0x900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the second query?

Comment: Nothing, it results the same

Comment: It will also match `0x900170983CF26FB0F6963F7D28E17F72` in a case insensitive collation as you are getting string comparison semantics and `0x70` = `0x50` in that case (`P` and `p`)

Comment: Also, parenthesis is not the right nomenclature, they are called quotes.

Comment: Appreciate that :)